# Why is it only the first CSS Selector working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS file for my web page, and it isn't working. I know it's linked correctly, because the all the elements in my first selector - `body` - work, but nothing after that renders. Does anyone know why that is?

**CSS**

```
body { 
    font-family: "Segoe UI"; 
    width: 400px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
}; 

body #changeInfo {
    color: blue; 
    font-style: bold; 
}; 

body #changeInfo:hover {
    font-style: italic;
}; 

body #footer {
    font-size: 10px; 
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    Welcome!
    <div id="changeInfo"> Enter different words here!</div> 
    <br>
    <div id="warning">Warning!<br></div> 
    <div id="footer">Footnote<br></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: why include body in those selectors?

Comment: An attempt to figure out what was wrong. It doesn't work with or without `body` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you use "**;**" after css rule. It must be like that:

```
body { 
  font-family: "Segoe UI"; 
  width: 400px; 
  font-size: 16px; 
}

#changeInfo {
color: blue; 
font-style: bold; 
}

#changeInfo:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

#footer {
  font-size: 10px; 
}
```

Your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/RomanGroovyDev/w74u8kax/2/

Comment: Thanks! It works now.